# How to compare two dataframes using column index?

Tags: python, pandas

I am exporting hdfs query output into a csv file using INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY command. Since this export the data without header.
I got another dataframe from Oracle output with file header which I need to compare against hdfs output.

```py
df1 = pd.read_csv('/home/User/hdfs_result.csv', header = None)
print(df1)

      0  1                    2
0  XPRN  A  2019-12-16 00:00:00
1  XPRW  I  2019-12-16 00:00:00
2  XPS2  I  2003-09-30 00:00:00


df = pd.read_sql(sqlquery, sqlconn)


  UNIT  STATUS Date
0  XPRN  A     2019-12-16 00:00:00
1  XPRW  A     2019-12-16 00:00:00
2  XPS2  I     2003-09-30 00:00:00
```

Since df1 is having no header i cant use Merge or Join to compare data. Though I can do df-df1.

Please suggest how can i compare and print the difference?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the underlying numpy array for comparison:

```
df2.where(df2==df1.values)
```

Output (difference are masked as `NaN`)

```
   UNIT STATUS                 Date
0  XPRN      A  2019-12-16 00:00:00
1  XPRW    NaN  2019-12-16 00:00:00
2  XPS2      I  2003-09-30 00:00:00
```

For non matching row:

```
df2[(df2!=df1.values).any(1)]
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I need to find non matching rows. 
I can do it using
cmp =  (df1 - df2)
diff = cmp.drop_duplicates(keep=False)

Pleas elet me know if there is any other approach i can follow?